# Select Parents if name matches on Parent or Child

Tags: sql

I want to create an SQL Query that returns a list of Parent rows, if a given name matches either the name of a Parent or the name of a Child. Thus, if the name matches a Parent, return that Parent. If the name matches a Child, return the Parent of that Child. No Parent row should appear more than once in the result.

Consider this example (Run the snippet for some nice HTML tables):

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Parent table</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Karl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Robert</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h2>Child table</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>parent</th>
    <th>name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Samuel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Karl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Robert</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h2>Result for Karl</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Karl</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h2>Result for Robert</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Karl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Robert</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h2>Result for Samuel</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Robert</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT Parent.*
FROM Parent,
     Child
WHERE Parent.name = :name_parameter
   OR Child.name = :name_parameter AND Child.parent = Parent.id
```

It doesn't work though, the result is always empty.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Tip 2: `AND` goes before `OR`. Use parentheses if you want other order.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, provide sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) Also read [mcve].

Comment: I've updated my question with some tables. (Are HTML tables the way to go to display SQL tables?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct Parent.*
from Parent
left join Child on Child.parent = Parent.id
where Parent.name = :name_parameter
or Child.name = :name_parameter
```

`distinct` removes duplicates.
`left` still returns parents who don’t have children.

Comment: This query should work; there's nothing complicated about it so look elsewhere for bugs. Manually verify that the names in your DB are actually the same as your parameter values, for example, are there leading spaces or trailing spaces or newlines in the data? Debug your code and make sure the parameter really does contain what you think it does. If debugging is hard, try inserting rows into a separate table passing in `:name_parameter`, then query the DB to see exactly what was inserted and compare that to your data. Are `Child.parent` values correct?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem: your query doesn't return Parents which have no children (the JOIN is empty). Matching Parents should also be returned, wether or not they have children.